# Keep track of multiple files loading using FileReader

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I am trying to keep track of several downloads with FileReader in a Meteor project.

What I want to do is to let the user select several files with a `file` input, and then let him track the loading of all of these files in a table.

Here is the concerned code in `home.js` :

```
Template.home.created = function () {
    CSVFiles = new Mongo.Collection(null);
};

Template.home.helpers = function () {
    'files' : function () {
        return CSVFiles.find();
    },
};


Template.home.rendered = function () {
    var global_id = 1;

    $(':file').change( function() {
        var files = this.files;
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            var id = global_id++;
            CSVFiles.insert({
                'id' : id
                , 'name' : files[i].name
                , 'progress' : 0
            });

            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsText(files[i]);

            reader.onprogress = function (data) {
                if (data.lengthComputable) {
                CSVFiles.update({'id': id}, {$set: {
                        'progress': parseInt(((data.loaded / data.total) * 100), 10)
                    }});
                }
            }

            reader.onload = function () {
                CSVFiles.update(
                    { 'id': id },
                    { $set: {'progress': 100} }
                );
            }
        }
    });
};
```

`home.html` :

```
<input name='file' type="file" multiple />

<table>
    <tbody>
        {{#each files}}
        <tr>
            <td>{{id}}</td>
            <td>{{name}}</td>
            <td>{{progress}}%</td>
        </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

}

My problem is that only the last row updates "Progress", while the others just stay at 0. I am also curiousof what you think of the efficiency of this code, since while files are being loaded, I can hardly manage to select other files (my computer freezes).

Comment: This code does not measure the progress of fileupload, only the progress of the read from the file system.

Comment: You can replace "loading" with "reading" if you want, this code runs on the client side.